# rect of interest with rectangle or text detection vision. iOS, Swift

Tags: rectangles, detect, vision

Hi is it possible to use something like rect of interest with vision framework non meta data type view such as rect detect or rectangle text detect? I want to detect only text in the rect of interest. I have been looking for answers for this for 2 weeks.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 2):

```
let request = VNDetectTextRectanglesRequest(completionHandler: self.onHandler)
textRequest.regionOfInterest = CGRect(x: 0.25, y: 0.25, width: 0.5 height: 0.5)
```

Comment: then what does the result box coordinate will be?